# RESTful resource returns HTTP 204, yet client displays 200

Tags: rest, http, jersey, jax-rs, java-ee-6

I'm writing RESTful Web service. The technologies that I use:

- Glassfish 3 (based on Java EE 6)
- Jersey (part of the application server)
- JDK v7
- Eclipse EE Kepler IDE

The resource method:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
@Path("/uploadDownloadFile")
public Response uploadDownloadFile(InputStream input){

    if(Files.exists(Paths.get(resource))){//stream data out
        ...
    }
    else{
        String result = "The file \""+downFileName+"\" has not been found!";

        ByteArrayOutputStream b = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        try {
            b.write(result.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        response = Response.status(204).entity(b.toByteArray()).build();
    }

    return response;
}
```

That is, when the file does not exists, the status of response is `204`.

The client part:

```
int code = connect.getResponseCode();

System.out.println("Upload Status: "+code+" : "+connect.getResponseMessage());

InputStream input = connect.getInputStream();

if(code > 200){
    downFileName = "Err.txt";
}

saveFile(input, downFileName);
```

Now, what I do is that I execute the client code, and make sure that the service method receives a file which is not available. That means, the response from the service method supposed to include the code `204`.

Although, when I actually execute the client, I get following status report (at above source code):

```
Upload Status: 200 : OK
```

**Additional Info:**

When I run debugger on the client side, I get into this JDK (`HttpURLConnection.class`) method:

```
/**
     * Gets the status code from an HTTP response message.
     * For example, in the case of the following status lines:
     * <PRE>
     * HTTP/1.0 200 OK
     * HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized
     * </PRE>
     * It will return 200 and 401 respectively.
     * Returns -1 if no code can be discerned
     * from the response (i.e., the response is not valid HTTP).
     * @throws IOException if an error occurred connecting to the server.
     * @return the HTTP Status-Code, or -1
     */
 ` public int getResponseCode() throws IOException {}`
```

It turns out, at the very beginning, that the `responseCode` is `-1`, which means, according to above doc: `the response is not valid HTTP`. In the end, it winds up into `HTTP 200` code.

Wikipedia:

```
 204 No Content
    The server successfully processed the request and is not returning any content
```

Why does the client has the status code which is not the same as Response from the service?

Comment: What is `Files`? What is `Paths`? You did look at this in the debugger, right?

Comment: Both come from Java SE API i.e., for File , and Path operations